# How to solve the error in installing Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pip

I tried to install TensorFlow using **pip install tensorflow** and I got the below error. Is that because of a timeout problem? How to overcome this error when installing TensorFlow?

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 425, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 507, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\http\client.py", line 454, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\http\client.py", line 498, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
```

Comment: are you using a conda environment? if not try: `pip --default-timeout=300 install tensorflow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using `conda` first run:

```
conda config --set ssl_verify no
```

after that modify your default timeout:

```
pip --default-timeout=900 install tensorflow
```

Note: `conda config --set ssl_verify no` only applicable for `conda` if you are not on `conda` env skip this step.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
pip --default-timeout=300 install tensorflow
```

This has worked for me as commented by Kenan since I'm using a *non-conda* environment.